# How does time freeze affect wider area when it's said to have limited range?

Tags: plot-explanation, freaks

**FREAK - Is someone with supernatural ability.**

So in the movie Freaks, The freaks have superpowers, One of the main character's superpower is to slow time. When he does that everything slows down for everyone except the Freaks.

So they have this mission of saving another Freak(The kid's mom) from the magic mountain. When doing so they are confronted with cops and the main character has to time freeze the house so the kid gets enough time to help her mom escape.

How does the time freeze affect whats happening at the magic mountain when it was clearly defined earlier in the movie that the freeze can only have a certain radius?

We know the time freeze doesn't affect other freaks, but how does it affect freaks visions?